# Python, insert XML data to sqlite3

Tags: python, xml, sqlite

Im trying to pull some XML from a URL, parse it and store the entries in an sqlite3 database, Im trying numerous things and all are failing.  Codde so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from urllib2 import urlopen
import gc
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

rosetta_url = ("https://boinc.bakerlab.org/rosetta/team_email_list.php?teamid=12575&account_key=Y&xml=1")

root = ET.parse(urlopen(rosetta_url)).getroot()
cpids = [el.text for el in root.findall('.//user/cpid')]
print cpids

conn = sqlite3.connect("GridcoinTeam.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GRIDCOINTEAM (cpid TEXT)''') 
c.executemany("INSERT INTO GRIDCOINTEAM VALUES (?);", cpids)
conn.commit()       
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect("GridcoinTeam.db")
c = conn.cursor()
cpids = c.execute('select cpid from GRIDCOINTEAM').fetchall()
conn.close()

print cpids

gc.collect()
```

Im getting the error:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 32 supplied.
```

I tried making the insertion tuples by changing to

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO GRIDCOINTEAM VALUES (?);", (cpids, ))
```

but that just gives:

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3289 supplied.
```

The XML extract is in the form ['5da243d1f47b7852d372c51d6ee660d7', '5a6d18b942518aca60833401e70b75b1', '527ab53f75164864b74a89f3db6986b8'], but there are several thousand entries.

Thanks.

Comment: XML and downloading of data has nothing to do with the problem. As you have proven with the print line, the `cpids` list is correctly defined. Next time please try to shrink the problem to the relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert this as multiple rows instead of multiple columns into one row

```
cpids = [el.text for el in root.findall('.//user/cpid')]
cpids = zip(*[iter(cpids)]*1)
print cpids
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt know how to fix that list format, it works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO GRIDCOINTEAM VALUES (?);", cpids)
```

This `executemany` expects a list of tuples, but you pass a list of strings. What the code does effectively is:

```
for entry in cpids:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO GRIDCOINTEAM VALUES (?);", *entry)
```

Note the star before `entry`, which unloads the string, and which gives you 32+ params whereas you only want one.

In order to fix that we'd need to know your `GRIDCOINTEAM` table schema. If you have a table with only one column and you want to insert that, you could probably do this:

```
for entry in cpids:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO GRIDCOINTEAM VALUES (?)", entry)
```

In contrast to `executemany`, `execute` takes each parameter as one param - no tuples and lists unloading here.

Alternatively you can resort to using `executemany`, but you'd then need to wrap every one of your strings in a tuple or generator:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO GRIDCOINTEAM VALUES (?);", [(i,) for i in cpids])
```